# Drawing and storing objects by clicking the mouse button

Tags: java, swing, draw

I am trying to draw circle objects with each click and then store every circle object into an Arraylist, I don't know why my program is not working! If I removed the arraylist and the line that create a new circle object, the program will work. How would I make my program store all circuit objects into an Arraylist ?

```
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class CircleObj extends JPanel {
        private int rColor;
        private int gColor;
        private int bColor;
        private int radius;
        private Random rand = new Random();
        private int xStart;
        private int yStart;
        ArrayList <Circle> xxx ;

        public CircleObj () {
        xxx =  new ArrayList<Circle>();

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {

            xStart = e.getX();
            yStart = e.getY();
            rColor = rand.nextInt(256);
            gColor = rand.nextInt(256);
            bColor = rand.nextInt(256);
            radius = rand.nextInt(20);


            repaint();
            }
        }); // end addMouseListener
        }

        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(rColor, gColor, bColor));
        g.fillOval(xStart, yStart, radius, radius);
        xxx.add(new Circle());
        }

        private class Circle {
            private int x;
            private int y;
            private int r;
            private int rcol;
            private int gcol;
            private int bcol;

            public Circle()
                {
                x=xStart;
                y=yStart;
                r=radius;
                rcol= rColor;
                gcol= gColor;
                bcol= bColor;

                }




        }

    }
```

======

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class HW3 {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circles");
    CircleObj canvas = new CircleObj();

    frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setBounds(250, 98, 600, 480);
    //frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    } // end main
} //end HW3
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the new shape inside the `paintComponent` method, `paintComponent` can be called for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control, instead, create it when the `mouseClicked` event is triggered...

```
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {

    xStart = e.getX();
    yStart = e.getY();
    rColor = rand.nextInt(256);
    gColor = rand.nextInt(256);
    bColor = rand.nextInt(256);
    radius = rand.nextInt(20);

    xxx.add(new Circle(xStart, yStart, new Color(rColor, gColor, bColor), radius));

    repaint();
}
```

And then in your `paintComponent`, loop through the `ArrayList` and paint the circles...

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Circle c : xxx) {
        g.setColor(c.getColor());
        g.fillOval(c.getX(), c.getY(), c.getRadius(), c.getRadius());
    }
}
```

Now, you're going to have to modify you `Circle` class to provide getters which the `CircleObj` can use in order to actually paint the circles...

Alternatively, you could make use of the `Shape`s API provided within Java...Have a look at [Working with Geometry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) for more details...